# Opt out of performance monitoring on site hosted by GoDaddy

Tags: godaddy, load-time

I have a website that is being hosted by GoDaddy. When I check at the browser's console for issues, I saw an error:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://img1.wsimg.com/tcc/tcc_l.combined.1.0.6.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I don't remember any script or CDN resource from wsimg.com. So I check the page source of my website and I saw an injected script below before the html closing tag, which contains this script:

```
<script>
    'undefined'=== typeof _trfq || (window._trfq = []);'undefined'=== typeof _trfd &&
    (window._trfd=[]),_trfd.push(

    {'tccl.baseHost':'$BASEHOST'}),_trfd.push(

    {'ap':'$AP'},{'server':'$HOSTNAME'})
    // Monitoring performance to make your website faster. If you want to opt-out, please contact web hosting support.
</script>
```

So I thought of removing it by myself, but when I check my code, it wasn't there. So I took the advice of the comment from the injected script, to contact my web hosting provider, which is GoDaddy. Unfortunately, they still haven't responded.

So I took matters into my own hand, and saw other people from the internet having the same issue and they [found a solution](https://ph.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/how-to-remove-additional-quot-monitoring-quot-script-added/td-p/62592#), also [here](https://wallydavid.com/remove-godaddys-broken-monitoring-script-added/):

- Login to your GoDaddy account
- Go to **My Products**
- Click **Manage All** under **Web Hosting**
- Right beside **cPanel Admin** button is **Three Dots**
- Click the **Three Dots** and choose **Help Us**
- Choose **Opt Out**

This is the case for the old UI of GoDaddy, but now in 2020, I cannot locate this configuration. I hope to find an answer for this same issue using the new UI of GoDaddy.

Comment: My solution: don't use godaddy :P

Answer (score 5):

### 2020 Solution:

How to opt-out of this GoDaddy's program and remove the inserted script:

- Login to your GoDaddy account
- Go to your **My Products**
- Under **Web Hosting**, click **Manage** on the right-most of the desired domain/website
- Select the **GoDaddy Analytics** tab

[image]

- Scroll down and select **No, I don't want to participate in the program.** then click the **Confirm** button

Remember that you can only change again this setting after 24 hours.